# How to embed inline images from remote server (s3 bucket) in laravel email

Tags: email, laravel, embed

Refering to the docs I was able to embed images stored on my server using the following:

```
$pathToFile = '/var/www/html/public/assets/images/logo.png';

<img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToFile); }}">
```

However, I was not able to figure out how to inline embed images from a remote server.

```
// This does not work.
$pathToFile='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/logo.png';
<img src="{{ $message->embed($pathToFile); }}">
```

I have not tried "Embedding Raw Data In An E-Mail View".

```
<img src="<?php echo $message->embedData($data, $name); ?>">
```

As I do not know what the function is expection for $data and $name.

Anyone have a solution to recommend? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't really understand your question. Why would you want to get an embed remote image? Just pass the url to your email view file through a variable, `$image` for example and then create your image with `{{ HTML::image($image) }}`

Comment: Yah you are right! I was mistaken about why I "needed" to embed them.